# get selected date from sender

Tags: c#, calendar

I want to get selected date from object sender and pass that date to other method. so, how to get date from sender object.

My C# code;

```
  public partial class MonthView : MetroWindow
{
    AppController a=new AppController();


    public MonthView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        calMain.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public void calItemSelectedDate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //sender = calMain.SelectedDate;   
        //DateTime d = (DateTime)sender;
        //a.fetchAndPopulateForDate(d);            <------I want code here.
        //DayView Activity = new DayView();
        //Activity.Show();
        //this.Close();

    }

 }
```

Comment: What what is the sender in this case? You haven't given us nearly enough information to go on.

Answer (score 3):

The `sender` is always the control that raised an event. In this case it is the `Calendar`. So cast it accordidngly:

```
public void calItemSelectedDate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Calendar cal = (Calendar)sender; 
    DateTime d = cal.SelectedDate;
    a.fetchAndPopulateForDate(d); <------I want code here.
    // ...
}
```

(however, since you could also access it directly via `calMain.SelectedDate` i don't really understand the problem)